# Load image from gallery doesn't works twice

Tags: android, image, bitmap, gallery, mediastore

I select an image from the gallery. Now I load it in a temp-file and can show it in a ImageView. Everything works fine.

```
Uri uri = data.getData();

File file = new File(uri+"");

String fileName = file.getName();
String filePath = file.getParent();

Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);

//here come's the code to save the temp-file and so on
```

In the fileName and filePath I save the name and path for later use. Because if the user want to save the image I want to make a copy of them.

```
URI shown in the debugger: content:/media/external/images/media/12345
filePath:  content:/media/external/images/media
fileName:  12345
```

If I want to save the image I use the fileName and filePath to build the URI and want to do the same like above. But it doesn't works. I get a FileNotFoundException "no content provider" from the MediaStore. Hmm - before I deleted the App for a fresh testing there comes "No such file or directory" and I thought I eliminate the "no content provider" Exception with the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(filePath +"/"+ fileName);
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), uri);
```

Here I see also the correct URI in the debugger.

What is wrong?

I've set the permissions READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the fileName and filePath I save the name and path for later use

A `Uri` is not a file, and yours most certainly is not a file.

> What is wrong?

Your `Uri` has a `content` scheme. This is being served by a `ContentProvider`. You do not indicate where this `Uri` comes from, but I am going to guess that it is from `ACTION_GET_DOCUMENT` or something similar. In that case, like a Web URL that requires a working session, [your access to the content identified by that `Uri` is short](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

If you want to have longer-term access to the content, download it into your app, just as you would download content from a Web URL.

Comment: I get an image from the gallery over an Intend like:
  Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);

Comment: I want to do that - copy the image in my App, but to a later time. But I like also to get the real filename and the real path to the Image. How can I get this information from the "data.getData()" or the Uri? I like to save this information to reduce the possibility to have the same image twice in my database - I know, if the image moved to another folder I also have this problem, but that is another thing I have to solve later.

Comment: @chrispi: "How can I get this information from the "data.getData()" or the Uri?" -- you don't. There is no requirement that the `Uri` map to a file, let alone a file that you can access. If you want a file, copy the image, and do it right away, not at "a later time", as you no longer have access to it them.

Comment: I "accepted" the answer because this is the answer for my question - I didn't know that the URI is session-based and has some more information etc. My solution for my "copy later" problem is, that I copy the image first in a temp-file and later in my app. But for my problem to get the right path and name for the file I didn't have a solution until now.  Maybe I shouldn't get the pictures over the Gallery-Intent.